# Searchbar xamarin forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I a novice in Xamarin and C#

T want to add a dynamic searchbar (mean without pushing the search button) in my content view in order to search in my sqlite database.

I cannot figure out why it not working:

I have been trying to do  the same things like in  [this tuto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAmcxAmbLcA) but with database but the list cannot display because the app is stopped

Here is my method in the database:

```
//SELECT   words
    public List<MyWords> SelectWords(string keyword)
    {

        var myword = (from word in conn.Table<MyWords>()
                      where word.Word1.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()) || word.Word2.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower())
                      select word);

        return myword.ToList();


    }
```

Here is my method in the class of my contact page:

```
//search on the list view
        private void SearcMyWords(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // var keyword = SearchWords.Text;

            var words = mywordsdatabase.SelectWords("car");

              listWordsView.ItemsSource = words;


        }
```

Here is my xaml page :

```
<SearchBar x:Name="SearchWords"
                       TextChanged=""/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to specify a TextChanged handler for your searchbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to implement the actual handler for the `TextChanged` property. Change your XAML like this:

```
<SearchBar x:Name="SearchWords" TextChanged="Handle_TextChanged"/>
```

And add a method in your code-behind, which will probably look something like this:

```
private void Handle_TextChanged(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SelectWords(e.NewTextValue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you it has been fixed